# I've created app named lowercase and page named Lowercase, how to rename the page Lowercase to lowercase?

Tags: facebook-page

I have an application named 'tottepost' which start with lowercase.
And one day, I've created a page named 'Tottepost' which is capitalized.

When I created capitalized page, Facebook told me there is a app named 'tottepost'. But I didn't think about that caution seriously. 
I forget that why I've created capitalized page...

After I created capitalized page, I realized that all of photos uploaded from my app have a link "via tottepost". And also I realized that I can create a page for application from application's setting page.

But when I push "Create Facebook Page" button, they say "Invalid name. Creating content with this name is not allowed. Try another name."

So, what can I do for now?
If it is able to change a Facebook page name to 'tottepost' from 'Tottepost', it is a best way.
And if it is not able to do so I want to change Application name to 'Tottepost'.

Any helps appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

14 days have passed since I asked this question. Finally I could delete the page, and I pressed "Create Facebook Page" button in app's advanced setting page. Then I got same error "Invalid name. Creating content with this name is not allowed. Try another name".

This realize me that the reason of page creation failure is not existance of page "Tottepost". The reason is app name, starts with lower case "tottepost", is not match with facebook's naming rule.

So I changed my App's name to Tottepost, I finally succeeded to create a page associated with app. And after that I could edit the page name and the app name to lower-case "tottepost".

It's curious that they forbid lowercase name when creating page, but they allow to change page name to lowercase...

Anyway I've created the page I wanted. Thanks.